# Android: Text not being applied to Card

Tags: android

So I'm trying to create an app where the user will go enter some text in two edittext fields and when a submit button is pressed, it will close the edit window and then add a new card to the list on the main activity. I've set up all my code and everything works without error. However, no cards are added and when the application starts, there's one card which has no text anywhere.

## My Code:

MainActivity.java:

```
//The following lines of code are in onCreate() and setContentView() has been
//called

//Get the intent that launched the activity
Intent i = getIntent();

//Get the strings from the intent
String sig = i.getStringExtra("signature");
String lMessage = i.getStringExtra("long_message");

//Init mCardView
mCardView = (CardUI) findViewById(R.id.cardsview);

//Allow swipe to delete for cards
mCardView.setSwipeable(true);

//Add new card with the two extra strings from the edit text fields
mCardView.addCard(new MyCard(sig, lMessage));

//Draw the cards
mCardView.refresh();
```

AddText.java

```
//The following lines of code are in onCreate() and setContentView() has been
//called

//Find edit text's and button
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_message);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_signature);

//Get the string from the edit text...whatever it may be.
final String signature = name.getText().toString();
final String longMessage = message.getText().toString();

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Make a new intent to start main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), YearbookMain.class); 

        //Put extras into intent
        intent.putExtra("signature", signature);
        intent.putExtra("long_message", longMessage);

        //Start intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Again, I'm not getting any crashes it's just that the card is not being edited. I've tried everything I can think of so I'm hoping someone can think of something else!

Thanks

Comment: CardUI is not part of the Android API. Nor is your question about Java. Please use the appropriate tags.

Comment: I don't have enough rank to create custom tags. I'm merely using the library to make something in Android so I think it's on topic.

Comment: "the library"? A quick Google search returns more than 5 libraries that mimic the Google Card UI.

Comment: I think your missing my question: I'm trying to find a solution to why the text that is being entered is not being added to the card. If I wanted help on searching Google for things, I would have searched for that on Google. No offense or anything.